# In my app i want to select multiple image but it is possible only first time

Tags: android, image

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'

Comment: Paste your code here

Comment: without code it is not possible to solve your problem